# How to connect to remote MS SQL Server from python using py(py)odbc

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu

I have a remote ms sql server at office location and I wanted to connect from an ubuntu desktop to it. I installed DBeaver http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ and it was working like a charm without any other dependency.

After this I started to setup a connection from python with no success until I found a straightforward tutorial at https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/. But this solution involved installing some packages to ubuntu itself and configuring some related config files in the system.

The question is if there is some python package to use without os dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to achieve what you want without installing some packages. Reason being you are connecting to the MSSQL which follows a different set of rules as it is from Microsoft.

If you were connecting to any DB (MySQL,MongoDB etc) you still need to install a package or module to make it work.

Try to install the package as described in the tutorial from the like you shared and if you run into any problem paste the problem here.

Comment: there is no problem with the solution as described, I did it and it works well. it is just not very useful as a solution for distribution.

Comment: after digging more into it I understand that there is no python only package to work with ms sql server. however it is do-able the audience for such a solution is so small and the users are never end users that nobody will bother even to try it.